# Trigger code when either observable updates

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a couple of observables on my state service generated from a behavior subject:

```
_state.sortModels$.subscribe(sortModels => {
    //do stuf
});

_state.filterModel$.subscribe(filterModel => {
    //do stuff
});
```

I want to have some code that executes when either observable updates.  So for instance if `sortModels` updates it will trigger subscription and use previous version of `filterModel` and vice versa.

Something like:

```
.subscribe((filterModel, sortModels) => {
    someMethod(filterModel, sortModels);
});
```

I find the RXJS documentation difficult to interpret for this use case as in all their examples it is timers outputting a number, not distinct objects.

In my container component how do I merge the two observables so if either update I can trigger code with both vales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) is **exactly** what you need:

> Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are calculated from the latest values of each of its input Observables

```
combineLatest(_state.sortModels$,_state.filterModel$)
    .subscribe(([sortModels,filterModel])=>{
        someMethod(filterModel, sortModels);
    })
```